# How to correlate two different sets of data using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

As my question is lengthy one, so let's quickly jump into it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinDayInfo]     --Table to get Financial Year , Month and Week information against a date
(
    [CalDate] [date],
    [WeekNo] [numeric] (18, 0),
    [FinYear] [numeric] (18, 0),
    [FinMM] [int]
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinDayInfo] ( [CalDate] ,[WeekNo] ,[FinYear] ,[FinMM] )
VALUES ('2016-06-27' , 1 ,  2017 ,  1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinDayInfo] ( [CalDate] ,[WeekNo] ,[FinYear] ,[FinMM] )
VALUES ('2016-08-03' , 6 ,  2017 ,  2)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinDayInfo] ( [CalDate] ,[WeekNo] ,[FinYear] ,[FinMM] )
VALUES ('2016-08-08' , 7 ,  2017 ,  2)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinDayInfo] ( [CalDate] ,[WeekNo] ,[FinYear] ,[FinMM] )
VALUES ('2016-08-15' , 8 ,  2017 ,  2)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Act]    --Accounts table having Financial Week and Shop-wise data
( 
    [FinYear] [int],
    [FinMonth] [int],
    [FinWeek] [int],
    [ShopCode] [int],
    [ActVal] [decimal] (18, 6) 
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017,      1 ,     2 , 1234 ,      10)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     1 ,     3 ,     1234 ,      50)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     1 ,     4 , 1234 ,      40)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     1 ,     5 , 1234 ,      20)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     2 ,     6 , 1234 ,      100)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     2 ,     7 , 5678 ,      90)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACT] ( [FinYear] ,[FinMonth] ,[FinWeek] ,[ShopCode] ,[ActVal] )
VALUES ( 2017 ,     2 ,     8 ,     1290 ,      100)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sal]    --Sales data table
(
    [SalDate]   [Date],
    [ShopCode]  [int],
    [ItemCode]  [nvarchar](10),
    [SaleVal]   [decimal] (18,6)
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-06-27',  1234,       '111PN' ,   5 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-03',  1234,       '100AB' ,   50 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-03',  1234,       '100BC' ,   60 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-03',  1234,       '110JK' ,   40 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-08',  5678,       '122AB' ,   90 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-15',  1290,       '111PN' ,   35 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sal] ( [SalDate] ,   [ShopCode] ,    [ItemCode] ,    [SaleVal] )
VALUES ( '2016-08-15',  1290,       '123CD' ,   35 )
```

From this data I need results as below (or from attached image).

Purpose of this data is to get Adjustment Value Item and Shop-wise on Weekly basis. This adjustment is allocated to each Item according to it's Sales contribution. "ActVal" is standard value in this regards and we calculate Adjustment Value from the difference of "ActVal" and "TotalSalePerShopAndWeek". This way, if we add-up "TotalSalePerShopAndWeek" and sum of "AdjustmentVal", it should be equal to "ActValPerShopAndWeek".

So to correlate these two Data Sets, I tried CTEs, Full Joins yet I've been unable to join it properly.

Can you help me to get below results ?

(I couldn't format results properly here, therefore I've attached image for this).

[image]

```
FinYear FinMonth    FinWeek ShopCode    ItemCode    SaleValPerWeekAndItem   TotalSalePerShopAndWeek AdjustmentPercentage=(SaleValPerWeekAndItem / TotalSalePerShopAndWeek)  ActValPerShopAndWeek    AdjustmentValPerWeekAndItem= ((ActValPerShopAndWeek - TotalSalePerShopAndWeek) * AdjustmentPercentage)#[enter image description here][2]
2017    1       1   1234        111PN       5           5           1                                   0               -5
2017    1       2   1234        111PN       0           0           0                                   10              10
2017    1       3   1234        111PN       0           0           0                                   50              50
2017    1       4   1234        111PN       0           0           0                                   40              40
2017    1       5   1234        111PN       0           0           0                                   20              20
2017    2       6   1234        100AB       50          150         0.333333                                100             -16.66665
2017    2       6   1234        100BC       60          150         0.4                                 100             -20
2017    2       6   1234        110JK       40          150         0.266666                                100             -13.133333
2017    2       7   5678        122AB       90          90          1                                   90              90
2017    2       8   1290        111PN       35          70          0.50                                    90              15
2017    2       8   1290        123CD       35          70          0.50    

                            90              15
```

Comment: Thanks Ranjana for the correction, but looking for a solution as well :)

Comment: Can you define the relationships in English?  I'm guessing that FinDayInfo relates to Act by Year and Week, and that Act relates to Sal by ShopCode.  Is that correct?  Is that complete?  (It seems incomplete to me.)

Comment: Why isn't week 1 represented in the Act table?

Comment: Also, you need to specify how these tables relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The below should give you what you need

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

select  FinYear
,   [FinMonth]
,   [FinWeek]
,   [Act].[ShopCode]
,   Sal.ItemCode
,   Sal.SaleVal
,   Totals.Value
,   Sal.SaleVal / Totals.Value
,   Act.ActVal
,   ((Act.ActVal - Totals.Value) * (Sal.SaleVal / Totals.Value))
from [Act]
LEFT JOIN [Sal] on Sal.ShopCode = Act.ShopCode
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(SaleVal) as Value
FROM Sal as TotalSal
WHERE TotalSal.ShopCode = Act.ShopCode
) as Totals
ORDER BY Act.ShopCode
,Sal.ItemCode
,FinWeek
```

Let me know if that is of use to you, or if you have any questions